# Can I use one android SDK for more computers at once

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I have 30 PCs connected to a server with Xamarin installed on every device, but the thing is, the PCs don't have a lot of disk space, so I was thinking, instead of every computer using it's own Android SDK, would it be possible to use one SDK located on a server disk for all PCs?

Comment: Create a new partition in main system, a proper size of your `SDK`, move your `SDK` to that partition and freeze it, then share with other PCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mount a network share on all 30 machines and map the same drive path on each then yes, probably, technically you could share the SDK files and use that path.

*But*  I wouldn't do it, as you have no control.  It only takes on dev, on one machine to update the SDK to a new version / remove some component, remove another SDK and all 30 machines are affected.  If you really have 30 devs to manage then the cost in lost productivity will probably exceed to the cost to add a new hard drive - IMO